# ANSA wont start after upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, 12.10, intel-graphics

after updating ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.10, the CAE tool ANSA 13.2.3 wont start. I'm using a Dell Latitude E6330 (core i5-3320M, Intel HD  Graphics 4000). I get the following from LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose:

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/opt/ansa_v13.2.3/lib/linux/lib64/qt//lib/LIBGCC/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_3.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so))
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/i965_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/opt/ansa_v13.2.3/lib/linux/lib64/qt//lib/LIBGCC/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_3.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so))
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/opt/ansa_v13.2.3/lib/linux/lib64/qt//lib/LIBGCC/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_3.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so))
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/opt/ansa_v13.2.3/lib/linux/lib64/qt//lib/LIBGCC/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_3.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so))
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
 FATAL SIGNAL : 11 caught exiting !!
```

I checked in the Synaptic package manager that GCC_3.4-base is available, as well as i965_dri.so and swrast.dri are in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/ .

I'm not so much into this stuff but need this to work, so I appreciate your help on this. Thank you very much!